# Mimic Zeroc Ice RPC Implementation from java client and server

Tags: java, reverse-engineering, rpc

I have java client and server app which communicate using zeroc ice rpc (icep protocol), i don't have source code for the server app, i plan to mimic the client implementation and rewrite it in other language (ex: javascript). but i don't know where to start, or if my step to do that is correct.
so far what i do is decompile client app (fairly large), check which code send and receive data from server and try to implement those action in other language. is this correct? or is there anything else i should do/check?

Answer (score 0):

ICE has good docs, is free for some uses (last I heard, years ago), provides some source code, and supports numerous languages, including JavaScript apparently.  So you could potentially use ICE to write your client, and otherwise to clarify your requirements/task.